Google Charts trend line limit range start/stop from dataset
I am using Google Charts to make a line chart with trend lines. It works well, but the dataset is for the last 24 months and I would like the trend lines to only represent the last 6 months.
Is there a way to set the range for the trend lines?
Like this:

google.charts.load('current',{packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
// Set Data
const data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Price', 'Size'],
  [1,7],[2,8],[3,8],[4,9],[5,9],
  [6,9],[7,10],[8,11],
  [9,14],[10,14],[11,15],[12,3],
    [13,7],[14,8],[15,8],[16,9],[17,9],
  [18,9],[19,10],[20,11],
  [21,14],[22,14],[23,15],[24,3]
]);
// Set Options
const options = {
  title: 'House Prices vs. Size',
  hAxis: {title: 'Square Meters'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Price in Millions'},
  legend: 'none',
          trendlines: {
          0: {
            color: '#1b9e77',
            lineWidth: 10,
            opacity: 0.2,
            visibleInLegend: true
          },
          1: {
            color: '#d95f02',
            lineWidth: 10,
            opacity: 0.2,
            visibleInLegend: true
          }
        },
};
// Draw
const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

